# Why did CyclicBarrier.await(int timeout,TimeUnit unit) didn't throw TimeOutException here?

Tags: java, cyclicbarrier

Talk is cheap. Show the code.

`MyCyclicBarrier.java`

```
public class MyCyclicBarrier extends Thread{
    private CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier;

    public MyCyclicBarrier(CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrier) {
        this.cyclicBarrier = cyclicBarrier;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread start." + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);  //biz code
            System.out.println("Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is waiting for the other Threads."+
                    "\n\t\t\t\tIt's parties is "+cyclicBarrier.getParties()+
                    "\n\t\t\t\tWaiting for "+cyclicBarrier.getNumberWaiting()+" Threads");
            cyclicBarrier.await(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread end."+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

`TestCyclicbarrier.java`

```
public class TestCyclicbarrier1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int length = 5;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CyclicBarrier cyclicBarrierWithRunnable = new CyclicBarrier(length, () -> {
            System.out.println("the final reach Thread is " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("cost totally :" + (end - start) / 1000 + "s");
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (i != 4) {
                new MyCyclicBarrier(cyclicBarrierWithRunnable).start();
            } else {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                    new MyCyclicBarrier(cyclicBarrierWithRunnable).start();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread start.Thread-1
Thread start.Thread-0
Thread start.Thread-2
Thread start.Thread-3
Thread Thread-0 is waiting for the other Threads.
                It's parties is 5
                Waiting for 0 Threads
Thread Thread-3 is waiting for the other Threads.
                It's parties is 5
                Waiting for 0 Threads
Thread start.Thread-4
Thread Thread-1 is waiting for the other Threads.
                It's parties is 5
                Waiting for 0 Threads
Thread Thread-2 is waiting for the other Threads.
                It's parties is 5
                Waiting for 1 Threads
Thread Thread-4 is waiting for the other Threads.
                It's parties is 5
                Waiting for 4 Threads
the final reach Thread is Thread-4
cost totally :4s
Thread end.Thread-4
Thread end.Thread-0
Thread end.Thread-3
Thread end.Thread-2
Thread end.Thread-1
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no similar answer. Please help or try to give some ideas! And I just start to learn `CyclicBarrier`.

I wonder if I have misunderstood `CyclicBarrier.await(int timeout,TimeUnit unit)`. Threads 0 through 3 have already reached the barrier point that cost 2s.In the same time the final Thread started after 2s of waiting.After 1 second number 0 to 3 Threads reach the specified timeout which number 4 thread still excuted its own code. Here is the question: Why did `CyclicBarrier.await(int timeout, TimeUnit unit)`  didn't throw `TimeOutException` here?

Answer (score 0):

> Threads 0 through 3 have already reached the Barrier point that cost 2s.

This is correct.

> In the same time the final Thread started after 2s of waiting.

Correct. Note, by the time this thread starts, other 4 threads are awaiting the CB (3 secs timeout i.e., we have 3 secs until a `TimeoutException` can occur).

But thread 4 sleeps for only 2 seconds in the `run` method (we still have only 1 sec until the `TimeoutException`).

When it comes to `await`, it is the *last thread* - so it doesn't have to wait anymore. Hence the barrier action gets run and others are unblocked - from javadoc,

> If the current thread is the last thread to arrive, and a
> non-null barrier action was supplied in the constructor, then the current thread runs the action before allowing the other threads to continue.

If you make sleep for four seconds before starting thread-4, you would get a `TimeoutException`.

```
try {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
    new MyCyclicBarrier(cyclicBarrierWithRunnable).start();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Yes.I've seen that the Javadoc says If the current thread is the last thread to arrive ... then the current thread runs the action before allowing the other threads to continue.You can also try to provide a null barrier action in the construct.That doesn't throw Timeout exception either : ( That 's why confused me for days).

Comment: As for the fact that the program timed out by sleeping for 4 seconds at the end, I'm not asking the program to throw a Timeout exception(3 seconds would be fine if it did). I just can't understand why I am using await(int timeout, timeUnit unit) where a thread runs out of time without throwing a Timeout Exception.Thank you for your patience and I look forward to your reply : )

Comment: The fact is no thread exceeds sleeping the 3 seconds limit. The last thread (thread 4) reaches the await **after** the others have waited for 2 seconds (as part of `await`). The barrier action is completed within one second thus unblocking the 3 threads.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that the timeout starts when the thread starts:

> Threads 0 through 3 have already reached the Barrier point that cost 2s.

> After 1 second number 0 to 3 Threads reach the specified timeout

This is wrong. When you call

```
cyclicBarrier.await(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

it doesn't matter how long it took the threads to reach that point - the timeout is 3 seconds from the moment the method `cyclicBarrier.await()` is called.

Since thread 4 has only an additional delay of 2 seconds it still arrives in time.

---

To clarify further this is what the timeline looks like:

- t=0s

  - `main()` creates the `CyclicBarrier` and starts threads 0 to 3
  - the threads 0 to 3 start and call `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);`
  - main calls `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);`
- t=2s

  - `main()` starts thread 4
  - the threads 0 to 3 awake, print out something and then call `cyclicBarrier.await(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);` which means that they will be interrupted at t=5s (t=2s + 3s)
  - thread 4 stars and calls `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);`
- t=4s

  - thread 4 awakes, prints out something and then calls `cyclicBarrier.await(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);`.
  - since now all threads are within `cyclicBarrier.await(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);`, the condition for the `CyclicBarrier` is fulfilled and all threads continue
  - the timeout for thread 4 doesn't get used (because it is the last thread to reach the `CyclicBarrier`)
  - for threads 0 to 3 the timeout at t=5s is never reached

Comment: Thx for you answer!It doesn't matter how long it took the threads to reach that point - the timeout is 3 seconds from the moment the method cyclicBarrier.await() is called.I'm still a little confused about this.Are the 3 seconds counted from when Thread 4 called `cyclicBarrier.await()` ？If so, that would be the correct answer~

Comment: @KevinWyen I've updated my answer with more details about the timing of the operations